# On radio button click show text file data in textarea

Tags: html

When a radio button is clicked i want to see data inside textarea that is written in test.txt file in html.

```js
function radiobtn(proposal){
    document.getElementById("result").value=proposal;
}
```

```html
<input type="textarea" name="params" id="result" required><br /><br />
<input id="open" type="radio" name="proposal" onclick="radiobtn(this.value)" value = "READ"  >Data Entry<br>
```